# bidirectional with word document using Aphace POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx, bidirectional

I am trying to add some Hebrew text into a word document and it's work fine but when I add punctuation it's getting messy.

This is the code I run:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

    paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

    // make RTL direction
    CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
    CTPPr ctppr;
    if ((ctppr = ctp.getPPr()) == null) {
        ctppr = ctp.addNewPPr();
    }
    ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON);

    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("שלום עולם !");

    // create the document in the specific path by giving it a name
    File newFile = new File("helloWorld.docx");

    // insert document to newFile
    try {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        document.write(output);
        output.close();
        document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the "helloWorld.docx" I get:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj9sg.png)

And this is how it's need to be:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymfeR.png)

Moreover, I want the whole document to be RTL (even with bidirectional) and not just the specific paragraph.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

That's a well known problem using bidirectional text. The exclamation mark, as well as the space are not right-to-left characters themselves. So we need mark them as such, if needed. The `RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK (RLM)` is `U+200F`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text#Table_of_possible_BiDi_character_types.

Following code works for me:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;

public class CreateWordRTLParagraph {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
  CTPPr ctppr;
  if ((ctppr = ctp.getPPr()) == null) ctppr = ctp.addNewPPr();
  ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON);

  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("שלום עולם \u200F!\u200F");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WordDocument.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

 }
}
```

Note the `\u200F` mark **after** space and exclamation mark.

If the text lines are coming from a file, then marking single characters will not be best practice.
Then the whole text line should be marked as right-to-left text.
To do so we can embed the text lines in a `U+202E RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE (RLO)` followed by a `U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING (PDF)`.

Example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;

import java.util.List;

public class CreateWordRTLParagraphsFromFile {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("HebrewTextFile.txt").toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  for (String line : lines) {

   XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
   CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
   CTPPr ctppr = ctp.getPPr();
   if (ctppr == null) ctppr = ctp.addNewPPr();
   ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON);

   XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText("\u202E" + line + "\u202C");

  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WordDocument.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

 }
}
```

---

Using `apache poi 5.0.0` for `Bidi` `.setVal(STOnOff.ON)` is not more possible but `.setVal(true)` can be used:

```
  //ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON); // up to apache poi 4.1.2
  ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(true); // from apache poi 5.0.0 on
```