# why are parentheses (brackets) inverted in MS Word when written to from Java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm writing to an MS Word document (.docx) using Apache POI from a JavaFX UI. the String is in Arabic, and when it contains one pair of brackets, the output is okay, but when there are 2 pairs or a quote, the output is messy, even though it appears okay in Eclipse's console too. Here's my code:

```
try (var WordOutput = new FileOutputStream(whichFile, true);
     var MSDoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(whichFile));
) { //inside try block now
    List<XWPFTable> tables = MSDoc.getTables();
    tables.toArray();
    XWPFTable ArabicTable = tables.get(0);

    var ArabicRow = ArabicTable.getRow(0);
    ArabicRow.getCell(1).removeParagraph(0);

    //adding a paragraph with a right alignment:
    XWPFParagraph arabicParagraph = ArabicRow.getCell(1).addParagraph();
    arabicParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
    XWPFRun run = arabicParagraph.createRun();

    //PS: this pane (on stackoverflow) reverts the text but the brackets face the right 
    //direction. 
    String theString = "(هذا نص عربي) (هذا نص عربي آخر)"
    run.setText(theString);

    ArabicRow.getCell(1).addParagraph(arabicParagraph);

    MSDoc.write(WordOutput);

} catch(Exception e) {
    //my exception handler here
}
```

solutions I've tried include:

1. recreating the string using UTF-8 encoding, but didn't work:

```
theString = new String(theString.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

2. changing FileOutputStream() into a file that specifies the encoding also didn't work.
3. reversing the brackets manually using a StringBuilder didn't work.
   thank you in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67027275/problems-with-symbols-apostrophe-parenthesis-when-writing-rtl-language-with-a/67032658#67032658 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169497/bidirectional-with-word-document-using-aphace-poi/61170607#61170607. But you really should set `Bidi` to force `RTL` text and not only set paragraph alignment to right.

Comment: @AxelRichter, thanks! I actually am using Bidi to force RTL but only when the string is bidirectional. I actually wrote one lengthy algorithm to reorder bidirectional strings. But calling Bidi.getRunCount() returns 1 when the string is only RTL (even when it contains parenthesis. Also, I'm using Apache POI 5 and 
```STOnOff.ON``` does not exist anymore. :/

Comment: @AxelRichter, just downgraded to Apache POI 4 to use ```StOnOff.On``` value, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Using `apache poi 5.0.0` for `Bidi` `.setVal(STOnOff.ON)` is not more possible but `.setVal(true)` can be used. But your problem is not the `Bidi` but the mark of BiDi character types. Please read my answers carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parentheses are not RTL text as your arabic text is. So it leads to problems if they are not marked as LTR text. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text#Table_of_possible_BiDi_character_types.

So either you mark each LTR character using `U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK` and then RTL characters using `U+200F RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK (RLM)`.

Or you are using `U+202E RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE (RLO)` before the text line having LTR charcters (`(` and `)`)  and RTL characters mixed and `U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING (PDF)` after that text line. That tells the word processing software exactly where RTL starts and ends. That leads to correct output for me.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;


public class WordTableRTLText {
     
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./source.docx"));
  
  XWPFTable table = doc.getTables().get(0);

  XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(0);
  
  row.getCell(1).removeParagraph(0);

  //adding a paragraph with Bidi set to force RTL text:
  XWPFParagraph arabicParagraph = row.getCell(1).addParagraph();
  CTP ctp = arabicParagraph.getCTP();
  CTPPr ctppr;
  if ((ctppr = ctp.getPPr()) == null) ctppr = ctp.addNewPPr();
  //ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON); // up to apache poi 4.1.2
  ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(true); // from apache poi 5.0.0 on
  XWPFRun run = arabicParagraph.createRun();
  
  String  theString = "(هذا نص عربي) (هذا نص عربي آخر)";
  run.setText(theString); // will fail showing parentheses correctly in Word

  run.addBreak();

  //use U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK (LRM) and U+200F RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK (RLM)
  theString = "\u200E(\u200Fهذا نص عربي آخر\u200E)\u200F \u200E(\u200Fهذا نص عربي\u200E)\u200F";
  run.setText(theString);
  
  run.addBreak();
  
  theString = "(هذا نص عربي) (هذا نص عربي آخر)";
  //use U+202E RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE (RLO) before the text line having LTR charcters and RTL characters mixed and U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING (PDF) after that text line
  run.setText("\u202E" + theString + "\u202C");


  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./result.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: @Axel_Richter, thanks a million! this worked! and I did read your replies, sorry. I should ramp up my education on Strings, really. And the algorithm I wrote actually flipped each chunk of left-to-right text and right-to-left text in the string one at a time and finally collects them. Now I'm having a feeling it was reinventing the wheel, I guess. Thanks again!

Comment: so, I've been experimenting with the Unicode sequences in the Wikipedia article and an issue arose. I can't accurately tell which parts of the String is going to be English and which parts Arabic. So I found a way to isolate each in a substring. But which codes to precede which text? the Jargon in the wiki article reads like Latin.

Comment: @Mobbs 8: You want to mix English (LTR) and Arabic (RTL) in one paragraph? Well this is another thing. The above only is about having a whole paragraph RTL and handle single not RTL characters properly.

Comment: oh yes. That's my original intention. Previously, I used the Bidi class to collect each "chunk" (each continuous RTL or LTR text) in an array, collected these into an array; so an array of arrays, and reversed them then finally collected them in a String and this fixed the order (hehe). Then parenthesis came and ruined it till you pointed me in the right direction. So, I'm super grateful.

Comment: Also, the String doesn't just mix English and Arabic together, there's no fixed permutation to it either. BTW, this is such a huge problem for speakers of RTL languages. You'd normally see formal text either separating each in a line (subtitles, for example) which doesn't look pretty or (e.g. businesses) giving up altogether. My guess right now is to surround each substring according to its directionality with the appropriate unicode directional formatting characters.

Comment: @Mobbs 8: But for mixing LTR and RTL text chunks in one paragraph the paragraph should not be set `Bidi` and the chunks surrounded with `Bidi` character marks. This rather should be done using different LTR and RTL text runs in that paragraph. But this cannot be an answer to this question as this is about why parentheses are flipped. So you should ask another question about this.

Comment: aha, I see! several runs might just work, and you're right, this should be a different question entirely, thanks again (vielen Dank!)